# Git branches/forks/ commit/push

Tags: git, branch, push, git-commit, git-fork

So this is a very basic question but I have scoured the internet and I am still lost. I am only one day into learning git (for a job) and would really appreciate some help on furthering my understanding.

So far, I know that forking a repo is like creating your own copy to make changes to.

Branches are to be able to work on the repo individually and work on subprojects kind-of ? (the concept is not as clear to me quite yet).

Committing is like screenshotting your changes and pushing is like a final submit of all your changes.

Now I was designated with a small task involving one .html file. I am to alter and push this file back to the master.

This is where I'm lost, I've forked the repo on gitlab and created a branch within my fork on gitlab as well. I can add files and can commit from the terminal without error, but I don't see my commits on gitlab. And when I try to push I get the error that I'm "not allowed to push code to protected branches of this project". I am added as a developer.

All I have done was clone the original master provided to me, edit the .html, and added the file using

> git add filename.html

was i supposed to clone from my fork or branch in order to be able to push? I am extremely confused and would appreciate any helpful advice. Thank you.

> git status
>   On branch myorigin
>   Nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: The error you are seeing seems to be saying that you _can't_ push to that branch because it is protected, perhaps for very good reason.  Maybe you are expected to create a pull request instead?

Comment: I dont think so, I will try that though. I was told to fork , create a new branch, and push my changes to the master branch.

Comment: What branch are you on?  Can you include the full output of `git status` in your question?

Comment: i added the git status output @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: It appears you have a permissions problem with your Git account.  Stack Overflow cannot help you with this.